# Liquibase with mvn liquibase:diff doesn't generate the dropNotNullConstraint or addNotNullConstraint

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I am using the liquibase plugin with spring boot to generate the `changeSets`. Using `mvn liquibase:diff` I generate the `changeSets` with the differences between my entities and the database schema. Everything works correctly but when I modify the nullability of a `@Column` of my entity it doesn't generate the `changeSets`. It should be creating `dropNotNullConstraint` and `addNotNullConstraint`.

My liquibase.properties:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/update/db.changelog/changelog-master.xml

url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/...

username=....

password=....

driver=org.postgresql.Driver

referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:package.of.my.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=configuration.CustomPhysicalNamingStrategy

diffChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/update/db.changelog/changelog-diff.xml
```

I expect to use `mvn liquibase:diff` and liquibase should generate the `changeSets` of `dropNotNullConstraint` and `addNotNullConstraint` if I have modified the nullability of a column of my entity.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase hibernate extension has some limitations and some bugs opened related to this kind of migration, like https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/454 (it's not the same but related to).